# TFS 2017 Change Release summary description during build

Tags: tfs, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We're using Team Foundation Server 2017. After lots of releasedefinition-making, I'm stucking on a problem.

During the release, I receive a message which I would write directly into the release description summary. I checked for an such an activity in the Marketstore, but I haven't found one.

Am I not able to search for the right activity or is there another way for updating this?

Comment: I can‘t right now. I‘m gonna chech in 2 weeks

Comment: Not jet. I‘m enjoing my freetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you can only update release name with [Logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md), which requires agent version 2.132+. So the only way to update the release description is adding a powershell script in your release definition. The script is as below:

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string] $token
)

## Construct a basic auth head using PAT
function BasicAuthHeader()
{
param([string]$authtoken)

$ba = (":{0}" -f $authtoken)
$ba = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ba)
$ba = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ba)
$h = @{Authorization=("Basic{0}" -f $ba);ContentType="application/json"}
return $h
}

$getReleaseUri = "http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_apis/release/releases/$($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)?api-version=3.2-preview"


$h = BasicAuthHeader $token

$release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getReleaseUri -Headers $h -Method Get

# Update an existing variable named d1 to its new value d5
$release.description = "this is a test";

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$release2 = $release | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$release2 = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($release2)

$updateReleaseUri = "http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_apis/release/releases/$($env:Release_ReleaseId)?api-version=3.2-preview"
$content2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateReleaseUri -Method Put -Headers $h -ContentType “application/json” -Body $release2 -Verbose -Debug

write-host "=========================================================="
```

And with argument -token {PAT}. Check my screenshot below:

[image]

I've tested on my side, it can update release description successfully.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tested it. Had some troubles with the permissions, but everything is working fine now.